# OSQA translation issue: strings not present in django.po

Tags: django, translation, osqa

Trying to create a translation for OSQA

Fist I copied the FR locale to RU, updated the settings. Fine, Most things are working but now everything in the django.po file has been translated but still a few lines show up in English and I I cannot find them..

For example the string

> "Most recently updated questions"

in the upper sidebar content right underneath the number of questions. The string is just not present in the django.po

PS:
I installed OSQA on webfaction using the wiki script. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

The template sort_tabs contains

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% trans "active" %} {% trans "newest" %} {% trans "hottest" %} {% trans "most voted" %}
```

but I think the string is coming from the count.html template

```
{% spaceless %} {% load i18n humanize extra_tags %} {% declare %} answer_count =     questions.children_count('answer') {% enddeclare %} 
{{ questions.paginator.count }}{{ list_description }} 
{% if answer_count %} 
{{ answer_count }}{% trans "answers" %} 
{% endif %} 
{{ questions.paginator.sort_description }} 

{% endspaceless %}
```

that might narrow it down to questions.paginator.sort_description ?

Comment: I guess you've checked that the templates have the i18n template tag loaded, and the string is on {%trans "Most recently updated questions"%} tag...

Comment: Have you checked the `#, fuzzy` lines in django.po?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at OSQA source code "most recently updated questions" string is defined for translation in [sort_tabs.html](http://svn.osqa.net/svnroot/osqa/trunk/forum/skins/default/templates/question_list/sort_tabs.html) template and it is included in [django.po](http://svn.osqa.net/svnroot/osqa/trunk/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) (line 5466).

Please note that "Most recently updated questions" string from your example is different string then is found in found in OSQA repository (uppercased Most), I can only guess that you are using some other templates that ones provided.

If that is not the case, please use following command in OSQA source directory to find files which includes missing translation string:

```
$ find . -name "*.po" -exec grep -l "Most recently updated questions" {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I will check the 5466 line. But can you have a look at http://www.mamburo.ru/ or www.hozburo.ru (that I am translating) you will see the uppercased Most under the number of questions (in the sidebar). I have done an out of the box install on webfaction. Is that not the default template I am using?

Comment: This should definitely be sort_tabs.html template. 

It could be 1. sort_tabs.html has been changed - please post result of ``svn diff`` from /forum/skins/default/templates/question_list/ directory  or 

2. run find command from the answer above and post the result. 

You have run ``python manage.py compilemessages`` after changing po catalog?

Comment: ``svn info`` would return revision.

Comment: Yes, I have run compilemessages. As you see on hozburo.ru most strings are translated. My django.po stops at line 4465 so it must be an onder version I am running

Comment: you should run ``svn diff`` and ``svn info`` from directory where you installed OSQA. I recommend that you upgrade to latest version with ``svn up``. You can always revert to current version with ``svn revert`` (but run svn info before to know which revision you have currently. Hope that helps.

Comment: Still i get "." is not a working copy, no matter what directory i use

Comment: I would remove directory (or move it somewhere else) and reinstall OSQA again. If that does not work I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks so far, I will post also at Webfaction because they provided the script for the installation.

Comment: yes, in the end it dit. I have reinstalled with svn support, upgraded and created a new language file. Actually the problem was in the fact that there are some <strong> tags in text as well. Thanks for your help.