# guide to translating django application (OSQA)?

Tags: django, translation, osqa

I want to translate OSQA into my native language, but I'm a total newbie to Django.

I've seen that there are other questions here on SO relating 0SQA. ([especially this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342161/osqa-translation-issue-strings-not-present-in-django-po))
So if anyone could guide me how to accomplish this task. (I’ve done research before posting question here, but [I didn’t find anything understandable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/localization/#topics-i18n-localization))

Thank you for any answers, suggestions, tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the rosetta package. Here are more informations and a simple step by step installation. http://meta.osqa.net/questions/11183/where-do-i-find-italian-rosetta-language-pack